# finishActivityAffinity NullPointerException

Tags: android

[image]Am getting this Error in production. When calling finishAffinity in splashscreen.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, XML, or logcat output. Please post all text as text.

Comment: Post ur Log Activity

Comment: @AvinashRoy ->  android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1552)
android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1499)
android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.finishActivityAffinity (ActivityManagerNative.java:2898)
android.app.Activity.finishAffinity (Activity.java:4873)
com.surf2buy.tradifi.logactivities.SplashScreen.startTheApplication (SplashScreen.java:91)
com.surf2buy.tradifi.logactivities.SplashScreen.access$000 (SplashScreen.java:34)
com.surf2buy.tradifi.logactivities.SplashScreen$1.run (SplashScreen.java:65)

Comment: post ur Log activity not the error stack trace

Comment: I dont know whats causing problem, but another work around would be to create a new activity and finish it oncreate,   now instead of finishaffinity  use intent with flags clear top and new task to the newly created activity

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for splashscreen...

```
public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.hide();

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    }, 2*1000);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Just surround it by try case:

```
 try {
        ActivityCompat.finishAffinity(this);
      } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        finish();
      }
```

Comment: if i put it inside try catch block.. activity will never destroy. currently added no History in manifest. but want to know why this is happening in version 5.1